# Get Static Path for an Asset in react native

Tags: ios, react-native, filepath, camera-roll

In my react native app i am showing several images in `<Image>` tags and i load those images from local folder.

```
<Image source={require('./src/images/image1.jpg')} />
```

I want to save image when the user tapped on it.
I can get which image user tapped and pass it to the function. But i put a single image path to it.

```
_onPressButton(imgName) {
  CameraRoll.saveToCameraRoll( './src/images/image1.jpg' , 'photo').then(function(result) {
    alert(result);
  }).catch(function(error) {
    alert(error);
  });
}
```

But this gives me an error in iOS emulator saying it **cant find the image in the path**.

When i give as,

```
CameraRoll.saveToCameraRoll( 'https://i.imgur.com/JnrwMpZ.jpg' , 'photo')
```

It works.

But i want to save these files in my src/images folder.
How can i get a path of this image file OR get this done..?

I appreciate any help regarding this.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Here is my solution with Expo, worked in android and should work on ios too

```
onSave = async () => {
  const asset = Asset.fromModule(require('./src/images/image1.jpg'))
  if (!asset.localUri) {
    await asset.downloadAsync();
  }
  const uri = asset.localUri;
  CameraRoll.saveToCameraRoll(uri, 'photo')
}
```

Comment: i got this error ***The method or property expo-file-system.downloadAsync is not available on ios, are you sure you've linked all the native dependencies properly?***