# how can I upload video files to node JS from react native

Tags: react-native, expo

I have a video in the asssets folder of my project, and I 'm trying to send that video to my node js server, and then upload it to S3 Bucket.

when uploading a video using the website it works fine, but sending videos from react native is not working.
I'm unable to send the video file to the server all together;

here is the function.

```
  async function sendReq() {
    try {
      // Read the video file

      const videoUri = require("../../assets/videos/mr.mp4");
      console.log("recording: ", videoUri); // this prints 25 for some reason

      const formData = new FormData();
      formData.append("video", {
        uri: videoUri,
        name: "mr.mp4",
        type: "video/mp4",
      } as any);

      const res = await axios.put(
        `http://10.0.2.2:3001/request/fulfill/12`,
        formData,
        {
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data", // Set the correct content type header
          },
        }
      );
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("error", error.message);
    }
  }
```

I tried pretty much every thing I could find online, but couldn't find a solution. I want to be able to send the video Blob to the server, and then upload to S3 from the server.
I just using the Blob method, which is what I use on the website, but that didn't work either.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get Static Path for an Asset in react native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49006859/get-static-path-for-an-asset-in-react-native)

Comment: Not really, the await asset.downloadAsync() is returning this error

 ERROR  error [Error: You attempted to set the key `downloading` with the value `true` on an object that is meant to be immutable and has been frozen.]